# Problema en al lanzar eventos y procesos desde un servicio de Windows

Tags: windows, eventos, windows10, proceso

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto en **C#** en el que hay un servicio de Windows ([Windows Service Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685141(v=vs.85).aspx)) cuya función es generar eventos de teclado, de ratón y lanzar procesos.

El servicio en sí ya puede instalarse y ejecutarse sin problemas, pero cuando se intenta lanzar algún proceso o generar un evento, no lo hace.

Fuera del servicio se pueden lanzar todo tipo de procesos y eventos.

Al instalarse, se establece la cuenta LocalSystem, que, en teoría, le da permisos de sistema.

Aquí está el código del método **OnStart**, que debería lanzar el proceso de iExplore con una ventana de google:

```
    ///<summary>
    /// Executed at reception of Start command.
    ///</summary>
    ///<param name="args">
    /// It must contain the source and name used for the debug log, or be empty. 
    /// The source and log must be already registered, otherwise a write attempt would fail and leave the service in an undefined state.
    ///</param>
    protected override void OnStart( string[] args ) {
        // Update the service state to Start Pending
        ServiceStatus serviceStatus = new ServiceStatus() {
            dwServiceType = ServiceConstants.serviceType,
            dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_START_PENDING,
            dwWaitHint = ServiceConstants.startAndStopLatency,
            dwControlsAccepted = ServiceControls.SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP
        };
        SetServiceStatus( this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus );

        // We use the default source and log names
        string logSourceName = LogConstants.logSourceName;
        string logName = LogConstants.logName;

        // If the arguments define an existent source and log, we actualize our variables
        if( args.Count() > 0 && System.Diagnostics.EventLog.SourceExists( args[0] ) ) logSourceName = args[0];
        if( args.Count() > 1 && System.Diagnostics.EventLog.Exists( args[1] ) ) logName = args[1];

        debugLog.Source = logSourceName;
        debugLog.Log = logName;

        debugLog.WriteEntry( "In OnStart." );


        //
        // Esta es la sentencia que debería crear el proceso de iExplore.
        // Al ejecutarla fuera del servicio si funciona, además, el servicio
        // sin esta sentencia funciona a la perfección.
        // NOTA: Esta no es la funcionalidad real, pero bueno, tampoco
        // funciona.
        //
        Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe", "www.google.es");

        // Update the service state to Running
        serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = ServiceState.SERVICE_RUNNING;
        serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = ServiceControls.SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | ServiceControls.SERVICE_ACCEPT_PAUSE_CONTINUE;
        SetServiceStatus( this.ServiceHandle, ref serviceStatus );
    }
```

Para el envío de eventos se utiliza **SendInput()** ([SendInput function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx)) y el caso es el mismo que con el lanzamiento de procesos.

Comment: Que error o excepción te está dando?

Comment: Realmente, no sé si puede ser un problema de contextos. Desde el contexto de usuarios en que se ejecutan el resto de aplicaciones funciona.

Comment: @miguel, no da ningún error. Símplemente, el proceso no se ejecuta.

Comment: Por otra parte si no se ejecuta es porque se está produciendo alguna excepción no controlada. Tienes logs en la aplicación?

Comment: si, hay un log, pero el servicio continúa aunque no se lance el proceso. Lo compruebo escribiendo una entrada en cada comando.

Comment: @miguel, tampoco queda nada registrado en el registro Aplicación, de Registros de Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Si es problema de que necesita permisos de administrador lo que tienes que hacer es:

Ir a tu solución y `Click derecho en el proyecto-> agregar-> Nuevo Elemento`
Te aparecerá una ventana y ahí tendrás que buscar `Archivo de manifiesto de aplicación` lo agregas a tu proyecto y este te generará un archivo llamado `app.manifest` con datos predefinidos.

Abres este archivo y tendrás que modificar la sección de `requestedPrivileges` para poder concederle permisos de administrador.

La sección te debería quedar tal que así:

```
<requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">        
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
</requestedPrivileges>
```

EDITO:
Click derecho sobre el proyecto para agregar un nuevo elemento
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Buscamos el app.Manifest
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modificamos el nuevo archivo para que quede igual que aquí
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Ese archivo de manifiesto se encuentra en alguna librería? no lo veo

Comment: ¿Pueden adjuntarse imágenes a los comentarios o de alguna otra forma? es para mandar la captura de los elementos que me permite añadir.

Comment: @JOverlord Editado!

Comment: Acabo de probar a cambiar los permisos del servicio utilizando el manifiesto, pero sigue sin lanzar el proceso. Gracias, de todos modos @miguel.